# unexpected token error when trying to use console

Tags: java, ubuntu, compiler-errors, console

I'm trying to write following code that will ask the user their username and password:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Console console = System.console();
        String USER = console.readLine("Username: ");
        char[] PASSWORD = console.readPassword("Enter password");  
        Arrays.fill(PASSWORD, ' ');
   }
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
nameless@nameless:~/Desktop/File$ Console console = System.console();
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
nameless@nameless:~/Desktop/File$ String USER = console.readLine("Username: ");
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
nameless@nameless:~/Desktop/File$ char[] PASSWORD = console.readPassword("Enter password");  
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
nameless@nameless:~/Desktop/File$ Arrays.fill(PASSWORD, ' ');
```

Side Note: I'm trying to use this to enter a database in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Are you trying to execute a Java program as a bash script?

Comment: No. I'm simply doing javac and java for compile and run .java file.

Comment: If your file is named Hello.java, then you should do: 
`javac Hello.java` 
and then 
`java Hello`
You probably did: `java Hello.java`, which is not correct.

Comment: No, i'm not doing that.You can see the error is compile time, i have not run the program yet.

Comment: I bet that if you also post the exact command you enter that generates that error - better if as a screenshot that shows also the prompt - you will get a solution much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve the same thing with the native Scanner instead Console

Try this can be any help.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );) {

        System.out.println( "Username: " );
        String USER = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println( "Enter password" );
        String PASSWORD = scanner.nextLine();

        Arrays.fill( PASSWORD.toCharArray(), ' ' );

    } catch ( Exception e ) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```